# Spring MVC binding to same @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Suppose we have this code for login & we want if the credential was for admin page the RequestMapping be for admin & if it was for user credential the user redirect to user panel.
now, the main page of both oppose the same url as I defined in my code below, something like :

```
http://localhost:8080/project/{username}/main
```

my question is :

how we can separate these two method in here when they have the same RequestMapping "main" after the login checking finished inside the Controller class?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String welcome(@RequestParam("j_username") String username, @RequestParam("j_password") String password, HttpSession session, Model model) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {

    int checkAccount = uiClient.checkAdminAccount(username, password);
    if (checkAccount == 1) {
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
        return "redirect:/" + username + "/main";
    } else if (checkAccount == 0) {
        checkAccount = uiClient.checkAccount(username, password);
        if (checkAccount == 1) {
            session.setAttribute("username", username);
            return "redirect:/" + username + "/main";
        } else if (checkAccount == 0) {
            return "login";
        }
    } else {
        return "databaseError";
    }
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/main")
public String indexPage(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
    return "/user/userPanel";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{username}/main")
public String adminIndexPage(@PathVariable("username") String username){
    return "/admin/adminPanel";
}
```

I mean, is there any way like special tag or something that we can put for each Mapping & separate them after the login process finished so the admin redirect to adminPanel & the user also redirect to userPanel but both with the same url:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/{username}/main
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String welcome(@RequestParam("j_username") String username, @RequestParam("j_password") String password, HttpSession session, Model model) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {

    int checkAccount = uiClient.checkAdminAccount(username, password);
    if (checkAccount == 1) {
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
        session.setAttribute("userrole", "Admin");
        return "redirect:/" + username + "/main";
    } else if (checkAccount == 0) {
        checkAccount = uiClient.checkAccount(username, password);
        if (checkAccount == 1) {
            session.setAttribute("username", username);
            session.setAttribute("userrole", "Admin");
            return "redirect:/" + username + "/main";
        } else if (checkAccount == 0) {
            return "login";
        }
    } else {
        return "databaseError";
    }
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/main")
public String indexPage(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
    if ("Admin".equals(session.getAttribute("userrole"))) {
        return "/admin/adminPanel";
    } else {
        return "/user/userPanel";
    }
}
```

For simplicity, I didn't use Spring Security to check user role here.

Comment: thanx AnthonY, that solved the problem, Can you please give me a hint how you use Spring Security here

Comment: Well, to use Spring Security, you have to use it to authencate the user as well. There are some work here. If you want to do that, you can use Spring Roo to create a skeleton project and figure out how to apply it to your app.